# Open cv memory image and saved image are differrent

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I'm reading about local binary pattern and I've the following code to extract local binary pattern.

```
from skimage import feature
import cv2 as  cv 
img = cv.imread("image.jpg",0)
lbp = feature.local_binary_pattern(img,8,1,"default")
cv.imshow("LBP",lbp)
```

the output image look like this

[image]

the original image is
[image]
But when I save image and load it back using the following code

```
from skimage import feature
import cv2 as  cv 
img = cv.imread("image.jpg",0)
lbp = feature.local_binary_pattern(img,8,1,"default")
cv.imwrite("new_lbp.jpg",lbp)
newim = cv.imread("new_lbp.jpg",0)
cv.imshow("new image",newim)
```

the image looks like this.
[image]

why does this two images  looks different? can any body help me understand it?

Comment: Weren't you supposed to use `newim` while `cv.imshow("new image",img)`

Comment: @ZdaR yes you are right i've just edited the code.

Comment: Then the outputs must have changed as well @Mitiku ?

Comment: @ZdaR The made the mistake when posting to stackoverflow, not inside local code.

Comment: imwrite and imread are for **images**. Not all matrices represent images. Your "lbp" contains values which do not represent pixels. You can save/load as you would do for any other numpy array and you'll be fine

Answer (score -2):

Opencv have some problems while saving jpg images so you can use other formats like bmp

Comment: It should be **png** not **bng**.

Comment: Yes but it should be bmp

Comment: it could be any lossless image format, but this is not the case since the data don't represent pixel values.

Comment: Note OpenCV offers support for the image formats Windows bitmap (bmp), portable image formats (pbm, pgm, ppm) and Sun raster (sr, ras). With help of plugins (you need to specify to use them if you build yourself the library, nevertheless in the packages we ship present by default) you may also load image formats like JPEG (jpeg, jpg, jpe), JPEG 2000 (jp2 - codenamed in the CMake as Jasper), TIFF files (tiff, tif) and portable network graphics (png).For more read this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html)